# .NET Winform Keyboard control

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard, user-controls

Is there a winform keyboard control out there? I am looking for a control which I can drag and drop. This is for a warehouse application which have touchscreen capability, like the ones found in the resturant applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yort has post on how to do this on his [blog](http://yortondotnet.blogspot.com/2006/11/on-screen-keyboards.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a CodeProject article that details how to create a Touchscreen Keyboard:
[Touchscreen Keyboard](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/touchscreenkeyboard.aspx)

Comment: Wow thats an awesome looking keyboard for just drawing it in paint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [accessibility keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/accessibility/default.mspx#EIBAC) for this purpose.

Comment: Yuck! I was just playing around with the on-screen keyboard in Windows 7 and you can drag and enlarge it just like any other window.  I guess that's no the case for other versions?