# Is there such a thing as a virtual keyboard component/library for Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

There might be one for WPF but not sure about WinForms.

Comment: It's allready discussed on StackOverflow and you can find answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956879/net-winform-keyboard-control

Comment: Could you use the built-in on-screen keyboard? In Windows-7 I just type `osk` in the run menu and it pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there is something in C#, but there is a good library to simulate the keyboard inputs. So you can try to use it ([Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)) and develop your own virtual keyboard.

It's very simple to use for example:

```
//Simulate Shift
public void btn_Shift(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SHIFT);
}
```

Comment: It appears this is a wrapper for the WPF version